# Two factor authentication for community portal

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-community, developer, experience-cloud

I know that from Feb last week, two-factor authentication in mandatory for Salesforce.
Is Two-factor authentication is mandatory for community portal as well ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, as per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388806&type=1):

> MFA is not required for your company's Experience Cloud sites, employee communities, help portals, or e-commerce sites/storefronts. You don't have to enable MFA for external users who access these sites.

Comment: I have only posted an answer here because Google doesn't provide a link to this page in the first set of results when searching with the most obvious keywords.